# How to install Linux to a USB which copies itself to RAM on boot and then again flushes the changed data to USB on shutting down?

Tags: usb, live-usb, ram

I am a School Student where the Computers are not assigned to individuals and instead keep switching them up. We can only bring a USB Drive to transfer the programs that we created a the end of the session.

So instead of having to take my programs alone on a USB, is it possible to have an installation of Linux on a USB Drive (with Data Persistence) which on boot, copies all its required files to RAM so that the USB Drive can be plugged out during the session and on shutting down, the modified files in the installation can be overwritten in the USB Drive? It could prove much value for all students and I believe the OS on RAM could be beneficial to performance as School has poor hard disk speeds. Since all computers have 4GB RAM, a simple version of Linux could fit in.

Comment: look at debian-live boot images

Comment: Take a look at Puppy Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Live-iso's are what you want.

Any distro will do, Ubuntu is one of the popular choices. You can download the live iso [HERE](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Once the system boots, you can copy the programs you create on the USB itself or,  you could take 2 USB's and copy your work on the other one if by some reason you can't copy the contents on the live USB.